# Dump limit in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, database-size

I am trying to dump a database which has a size of just over 100 GiB. I am using the following command (with `pv` to give a progress bar to observe where this problem occurs):

```
pg_dump -h <host> -U <user> <db> | pv -c -s $(psql -h <host> -U <user> <db> -tc "SELECT pg_database_size('<db>')") -N dump | gzip > <db>.sql.gz
```

The dump chugs along happily until it reaches 56.8GiB raw passing through the pipeline (~25GiB of the compressed file), and then just dies. I am at a loss as to why this is happening. The filesystem is `ext4`, so it's not a size limitation there.

I'm currently running it again, but splitting files into 10GiB chunks. Let's see how this goes.

Any ideas why, no matter what, the dump stops at 56.8GiB?

EDIT: The server I'm trying to get the dump from is a pod running on Google Kubernetes Engine. I have tried dumping both on the pod itself, and from another pod connecting through a service, and the problem persists.

Comment: Do you receive any error messages? Or do you just terminate/kill the `pg_dump`? Are there any other "dumps" running?

Comment: No other dumps running. I do not kill the `pg_dump`, it kills itself. No exit code or error given

Comment: An original database size of 100Gb does not necessarily mean that a pg_dump will be the same size. It's almost certainly going to be smaller due to bloat / empty space. It might have finished?

Comment: The problem is, it fails to import into the new database. It will get ~60% of the way through at a fair speed (10-15MiB/s), then completely drop to ~50KiB/s. I left it overnight in case it was just taking a while to process the import, but it still didn't complete by the next morning, after 18 hours of running.

Comment: Do you encounter the same issue if you leave the `pv...` part out of the equation? e.g. `pg_dump -h <host> -U <user> <db> | gzip > <db>.sql.gz`.

Comment: I've tried that one before, and yeah, same problem

Comment: Just curiosity, why u don't use pg_dump with `--compress=9` ?

Comment: How can it not produce an exit code?  Unless the entire OS crashes, there is an exit code.  Also, have you looked in `/var/log/*` for things like OOM killer and also at the PostgreSQL server log file for any info?

Comment: Your question says the problem is with pg_dump, but your comment says the problem is with the restore.  Can you clarify what the problem actually is?